# Are transactions in PostgreSQL via `psycopg2` per-cursor or per-connection?

Tags: postgresql

I'm doing some work with PostgreSQL 9.3 using the `psycopg2` database API.

I have the DB API set in the minimum isolation level ("autocommit" mode), and am managing my own transactions directly via SQL. Example:

```
cur = self.conn.cursor()
cur.execute("BEGIN;")
cur.execute("SELECT dbId, downloadPath, fileName, tags FROM {tableName} WHERE dlState=%s".format(tableName=self.tableName), (2, ))
ret = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Basically, Is the transaction that is started by the `cur.execute("BEGIN;")` limited to just that cursor, or is it for the whole connection (`self.conn.cursor()`)?

Some of the more complex things I am doing involve multiple separate database operations, that I logically break down into functions. Since this is all in a class which has the connection as a member, it's a lot more convenient to create cursors within each function. However, I'm not sure how creating cursors *within* a transaction works.

Basically, if transactions are per-connection, I can just create lots of cursors on-the-fly within the transaction. If they're per-cursor, that means I have to pass the cursor around everywhere. Which is it?

The documentation does not touch on this, though the fact that you can call `connection.commit()` makes me *fairly* confident the transaction-control is per-connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Transactions are per-session, i.e. per-connection.

PostgreSQL doesn't support suspending and resuming transactions, so psycopg2 couldn't make them per-cursor unless it implicitly created new connections behind the scenes.

In practice I don't find psycopg2's cursors particularly useful. They can retain result sets if you're not using incremental fetch from the server, but I don't find them good for much else.

Why manually issue `begin` and `commit` though, rather than using the connection methods for them?

Comment: AFICT from the documentation, the whole "DB API" model doesn't really support explicit transactions at all.

Comment: @FakeName You don't have to explicitly `begin`. If no transaction is open, a new one is started for you. You just `commit` to delineate transactions. So yes, the DB-API model *does* support explicit transactions.

Comment: If the DB api is doing it automatically without my specifically directing it to do so, that is very much an *implicit* begin. And besides, it's irrelevant, since (as I stated in the question), I'm using the autocommit mode, because I *don't want* those automatic `BEGIN` statements. I don't want `psycopg2` to create a new transaction for each `SELECT`.

Comment: TL;DR basically I want to know the exact scope of all the transactions going on because A. I'm crazy that way, and B. it helps a lot with debugging.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to see odd bugs popping up with this. AFAIK autocommit is really meant to be *autocommit* not manual-transaction-management. If you really want to manually manage transaction scopes, an extra `BEGIN` is harmless and will just be ignored by PostgreSQL with `WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress`.

Comment: I'm decided the way I'm doing things by reading a bit between the lines of the [`BEGIN` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-begin.html), which doesn't seem to have any notes about stability issues when doing transactions in autocommit mode.

Comment: Frankly, I really wish there was a way to turn all the DB API "helper" cruft off entirely.

Comment: @FakeName It's somewhat modeled on JDBC, which behaves similarly, using `setAutoCommit(false)` to delineate transactions. I agree that the DB-API implicit transaction begin isn't great, but it's also not too bad.

Comment: I guess the question then is how can I get entirely explicit commit behaviour? I want to have to manually issue *all* `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` commands.

Comment: @FakeName Perhaps you should post a new SO question on that topic. My impression is "you can't". (Ab)using autocommit may work for now, but it could be broken by a future psycopg2 release.

Comment: Yeah. Autocommit is breaking the stuff I'm trying to do with named cursors right now anyways, so it looks like that's a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 3):

From the [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control) documentation:

> In Psycopg transactions are handled by the connection class. By default, the first time a command is sent to the database (using one of the cursors created by the connection), a new transaction is created. The following database commands will be executed in the context of the same transaction – not only the commands issued by the first cursor, but the ones issued by all the cursors created by the same connection. Should any command fail, the transaction will be aborted and no further command will be executed until a call to the rollback() method.

At the same time, from version 2.4.2, there is the [`autocommit` attribute](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) (emphasis added):

> Read/write attribute: if `True`, no transaction is handled by the driver
>   and every statement sent to the backend has immediate effect; if `False`
>   **a new transaction is started at the first command execution**: the
>   methods `commit()` or `rollback()` must be manually invoked to terminate
>   the transaction.
>
> The autocommit mode is useful to execute commands requiring to be run
>   outside a transaction, such as `CREATE DATABASE` or `VACUUM`.
>
> The default is `False` (manual commit) as per DBAPI specification.